# Strange error conversion to dex failed

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-support-library, dex

When I try to run my project in Eclipse it says that it could not find the `project.properties` file and then throws the following error:

```
              Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoVersionImpl;
Dex Loader Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define   Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoVersionImpl;
ScanCard Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute  dex: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoVersionImpl;
Dex Loader Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoVersionImpl;
ScanCard Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute   dex: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoVersionImpl;
```

I have tried rebuilding by removing the v4 support library from the project and adding it using  the v7-appcompat library that I am usingI have also removed android.jar from the `Build Path` but to no avail.

The sdk path and the ndk path are set correctly as well,I checked to make sure.

Comment: what are the other jars that you are referencing in the project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your project contains several version of **android.support.v4.jar** file. Use same version of android.support.v4 jar file on your **MainProject and it's Library Project**.

android.support.v4.jar file exists on TestProject/**libs**/android.support.v4.jar folder.

Comment: I found a third version in one of the llibrary folders,removed it.

Answer (score 0):

Your Project has included a similar jar file more than once.
Check the lib folder of every project that you have added into the build path. If any of the library is present in another project than delete it from the current project.